# I can't add items from any dashboard (old or new)

Tags: scada, scadalts

I'm trying tu turn on and test ScadaLTS on my PC (Windows 10). Before read install instuctions, I have donwloaded and installed Tomcat and MySQL, configured context.xml and env.properties. I have restarted Tomcat before changes and navigated to localhost. All seems to work well. Login pagin is showed and I can log in with 'admin/admin'. I click on add view and new view is created. I go to edit button. When I try to add a new component, only two options appear (SLTS Image Componen and SLTS Visit Counter). If I back to old UI, add a view and then try to add a component, list is published as shown is youtube, but when I click on add, nothing happens. No items are added on drawable surface.

I was looking for errors in Tomcat log folder but nothing find. If I open Angular 2 UI with dev-tools, console show firtsly two erros:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found) ~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found) ~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css
```

And before them, two more are shown continously:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_has' of undefined
at p (plotly.min.js:52)
at Object.t [as relayout] (plotly.min.js:52)
at WatchlistComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/appBody/watchlist/watchlist.component.ts.WatchlistComponent.autorangeChart (main.bundle.js:3859)
at main.bundle.js:3635
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:33289)
at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:81064)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:33288)
at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (vendor.bundle.js:33056)
at webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:33363)
at ZoneTask.invoke (vendor.bundle.js:33352)
```

defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.bundle.js:78203

```
:8080/ScadaBR/api/point_value/getValue/null Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad request)
vendor.bundle.js:78203 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 400 Petición incorrecta for URL: http://localhost:8080/ScadaBR/api/point_value/getValue/null
    at resolvePromise (vendor.bundle.js:33648)
    at resolvePromise (vendor.bundle.js:33619)
    at vendor.bundle.js:33696
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:33289)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:81064)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:33288)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (vendor.bundle.js:33056)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (vendor.bundle.js:33460)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (vendor.bundle.js:33367)
    at invokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:34235)
```

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Java, Tomcat and MySQL are you using?
The problem can be caused by too high version of Tomcat. We recommend to use version 7.0.82.

The simplest way to run Scada-LTS is to use our docker container:
https://github.com/SCADA-LTS/Scada-LTS/wiki/Run-ScadaLTS-on-docker---instruction

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply.

I have installed Tomcat 7 (7.0.82), Java 8 (1.8.0_141) and MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Hi again r3miz3r.

Excuse me but I'm a noob using Docker. I have installed it on Windows 10 and I have followed every steps pointed in your link but again, I can't start ScadaLTS. When I run /root/start.sh, powershell shows "*Starting MYSQL..." "No directory, logging in with HOME=/" [fail] ERROR 2002: Can't connect to local MYSQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' and later, a lot of Java Exceptions related with mysql are logged.

Maybe have I forgotten anything related with MySQL that are not pointed in instructions?? It's my first time with Docker, :(